# React higher-order component - Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-functional-component

I've made a pretty straightforward higher-order component that fetches data from an API endpoint, and displays a loading spinner, an error message on fail, or a component on success.

The component works fine, but I get the following error message:

`Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
    in Unknown (at ApiData.tsx:34)` <-- this line: `ok: value => <WrappedComponent data={value} />`

From reading similar posts, I gather that React could be a bit overzealous on displaying this message. I am using a fully immutable Redux store and do not use any non-functional components. I am afraid that because I am getting this warning, if I try to extend this component later (say, by auto-refreshing the API every so often) that updates won't properly fire. Plus, it's a warning message - we should pay attention ;)

Below is the code to the HOC

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react'
import { IResult } from 'typescript-monads'
import { useDispatch } from '../../store'
import { PayloadActionCreator } from 'typesafe-actions'
import { Preloader, PreloaderSize } from 'react-materialize'
import styles from './ApiData.module.scss'

interface ApiProps<TKey, TData> {
  key: TKey
  data?: IResult<TData, Error> | "loading"
  get: { request: PayloadActionCreator<string, TKey> }
  loaderSize?: PreloaderSize | "inline"
}

export interface DataProps<TData> {
  data: TData
}

export default <TKey, TData>({ key, data, get, loaderSize }: ApiProps<TKey, TData>) =>
  (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<DataProps<TData>>) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    if (!data) {
      dispatch(get.request(key))
      return <span>&nbsp;</span>
    } else if (data === "loading") {
      if (!loaderSize || loaderSize === "inline") {
        return <span><Preloader className={styles.preloader} /></span>
      } else {
        return <Preloader size={loaderSize} />
      }
    } else {
      return data.match({
        fail: error => <span>An error occurred: {error.message}</span>,
        ok: value => <WrappedComponent data={value} />
      })
    }
  }
```

Here is an example on how it is used:

```
const somePart = ApiData<SomeObjectKey, SomeObject>({...})
...
return <div>{somePart(SomeComponent)}</div>
```

Can anyone suggest why this warning is being raised, and how to remove/resolve? Thank you.

EDIT: It was suggested that `data.match` might be a problem - I tried the following, too, and it still errors:

```
if (data.isFail()) {
  return <span>An error occurred: {data.unwrapFail()}</span>
} else {
  return <WrappedComponent data={data.unwrap()} />
}
```

Comment: Is `data.match` calling the function, or is it just returning the function? Calling the function would be an issue.

Comment: `data.match` is a function, but I tried two different ways of returning the value here - see the edit without a function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your parameters might have been in the wrong order. Typically for a HOC you want to take the wrapped component first, and return a function that take props and returns JSX involving the wrapped component in some way.

```js
// next two lines have been swapped
export default (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<DataProps<TData>>) => { 
  return ({ key, data, get, loaderSize }: ApiProps<TKey, TData>) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    if (!data) {
      dispatch(get.request(key))
      return <span>&nbsp;</span>
    } else if (data === "loading") {
      if (!loaderSize || loaderSize === "inline") {
        return <span><Preloader className={styles.preloader} /></span>
      } else {
        return <Preloader size={loaderSize} />
      }
    } else {
      if (data.isFail()) {
        return <span>An error occurred: {data.unwrapFail()}</span>
      } else {
        return <WrappedComponent data={data.unwrap()} />
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use your HOC like this:

```js
import HOC from "./hoc-file"

function OriginalComponent(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }

const WrappedComponent = HOC(OriginalComponent);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedComponent {...props} />, rootDomElement);
```

Comment: When reviewing various sources about HOCs online, I've found both variations. I chose the order I did because I could partially apply the API data spec, and then pass it different components second. I will try swapping the order and see if the warning goes away.

Comment: My concern is that React requires `(props) => JSX` for a function to be a component, and the other style returns `(component) => JSX` which React doesn't know how to handle.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing for a couple of weeks - other priorities called!
I see what you mean now - as I came back to this project and started introducing editable controls, I've noticed React is re-rendering everything under the HOC because it 'doesn't know how to handle' it. I'll try reversing the arguments and using them as you suggested now.